# share42 Plugin installation It cannot find the image in Laravel

Tags: laravel, share-button

```
    <div class="share42init" data-top1="20" data-top2="20" 
data-margin="80" data-url="http://localhost:8000/index" 
data-title="Help your employer find employees on social media."
```

data-description="Viral employee sourcing on social media." 
data-path="{{URL::asset('assets/img/')}}" >

This is in index.blade.php

I am trying to install the share42 plugin, but I cannot get it to work in Laravel. The problem is that it is simply not finding the icons.png image.
I can click at the respective place and it will share but it wont find the image.

How can I make the package find the image?

share42.com

Thank you.

Comment: Solved the issue. It was in permissions, so it couldnt find it with f + fn in the package. removing +fn in the Jquery solves the problem. The package was not made for laravel.